# Any tool to easily configure Windows Error Reporting, JIT debugger etc.?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg, utilities, windows-error-reporting

When your program crashes at a non-development environment, there are still ways to locate the error. You can have the Windows create a full crash dump, or you can have it attach a debugger such as windbg or NTSD before the process vanishes. However, configuring those options require probing the registry, and setting values that are hard to remember.

I'm wondering if there's any small and simple utility, that can easily configure [Windows Error Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219076%28v=office.12%29.aspx#MicrosoftErrorReporting_RegistrySettings), [JIT debugger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939482.aspx) and so on. Dr. Watson was able to do some of that, but he's retired now.

(If no such tool exists, I might have found my next side project...)

Answer (score 1):

You can make NTSD your JIT debugger with this command:

```
ntsd -iae
```

On 64 bit OS it will need to be done with two commands -- once with x86 version of ntsd, once with x64 version, so that you will be able to use JIT debugger for both 32 and 64 bit applications.

For the Windows Error Reporting, the officially supported way is using Group Policy. Launch gpedit.msc, navigate to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Error Reporting. Group Policy requires manual configuration of settings, you cannot script it, but you can deploy this to all computers in domain, provided you are domain administrator. I'm not aware for any tools that can make it easier for single computers, it would probably make a good project.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the GP option, but that too isn't really friendly... The need for domain-level operations is, at least in my case, an overkill. I can configure WER using the registry, but it's what I'm actually trying to get rid of.